# AWS lambda function in python loses dependency due to the folder name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dependencies

Now I am working on a project that is using AWS services. And I was making a unit test and got into this issue.

So first this project had a folder called `aws` and under that, `cloudformation`, `lambda`, and `test`.
my problem was i had to change the folder called `lambda`, otherwise i was not able to code like this. `from lambda import lambda_handler`. because the word `lambda` is already reserved in python.

so I changed the folder name from `lambda` to `function` and in the yaml template, the field `codeUri` to `../function`.
and this is where the problem comes in. this folder renaming cause the lambda function to lose all the dependencies.
I have no idea why.
I looked template yaml file, but there is no configuration that i was able to find about this issue.

here is the image of the dependencies on aws console before renaming the folder name.
[python dependencies on aws console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzxA4.png)

and as soon as i changed the name of the folder, it would be leave only `lambda_function.py and __init__.py`.

Please help me solve this issue if anyone as an idea what is going on here..
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you state you have a cloudformation template - post some of the lambda portion at the very least. You might also need to see where the dependencies are being uploaded - Are they being uploaded as a layer? or was there some other custom resource in your CFN template taking care of them? (uploading dependencies as just straight modules is bad practice with lambdas - they should either be mounted in a Layer or in an Elastic Files System)

Comment: I think this has something to do with the [layer paths](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-manage) that lambda follow. I had a similar issue with nodejs because I was not following the folder Structure naming but I'm not sure If this is the case for you.

Comment: are you using pytest framework?
we can make use of conftest.

Comment: guys. thank you for the help. it was due to the ci/cd yaml config. I had to specify the lambda function path.